# when i export a variable is there a way to control it so that it is only used once

Tags: bash, shell

I've made this very intricate login system that has multiple games that has multiple games. I have it running on a server and is meant to have multiple people on it at the same time. Now to have one of my bash scripts (Don't ask me why i used bash) get there game data from the last time they played one of thee games i have it access info from a directory. Now to my question. I was trying to use a export command to do this to get there username to the game and thus access the data. But since this is a multiple people playing this. If I export a variable it could result in another person getting that username and data.

Is there a way to control the export. I'm very inexperienced with export. So I do not know if it is already a controlled and only one script takes it. Or if it only exports to the shell scripts it is in. thank you for anyone who answers. I am very open to multiple ways of doing this as i don't know any.

Answer (score 2):

`export` only affects the environment of the shell instance it is executed in, so there won't be any interference among your users.

Comment: Ok great I had no clue had export worked as i had no need for it ever